# Kendo UI Grid - Binding to navigation properties

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using the Kendo UI grid and am display a role of models. Each model has a navigation property, and I am trying to display a field that exists in this navigation property.

```
  //schema for my kendo data source
  schema: {
                data: function (data) {                         
                    return data || [];
                }                   
            }
 ......................................................
   $("#FAAFreqGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: FAADS,

            columns: [
                   { field: "Id", title: "Freq ID", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
                 { field: "Frequency", title: "Frequency Test" format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" }, 
                  { field: "FREQ_POOL", title: "FAATEST", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }
            ],
            toolbar: ["create"],
            editable: "inline",
            pageable: true

        });
```

If I go to my Web API Url, I get a json response of:

```
[{"$id":"1","Frequency":"164.1375","FREQ_POOL":{"$id":"2","IsAM":true,......etc}
```

FREQ_POOL is my navigation property, and it has the data I want. Frequency exists and displays in my grid properly. But my FREQ_POOL field says [object Object], and if I try to say "FREQ_POOL.IsAM", it says IsAM is not defined. I cannot get it to bind to any property I can bind to any other non-navigation field. How do I make this work? The data exists in the JSON object that is returned, but the binding just isn't working correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a template for the column in question, like this:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
    field: "name",
    template: "<strong>#: name.first#, #: name.last# </strong>"
  }],
  dataSource: [ { name: { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe' } }, { name: { first: "John", last: 'Doe' } } ]
});
```

the template can then be used to show object in the dataset

more info, you could find [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template)

For the editing, you could then also define the cell editor, with an extra template or function, more info about that, you could find [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.editor).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have a slight issue related to this that I have created a new issue for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015105/kendo-grid-child-navigation-binding-issues