# Kendo Grid - Child Navigation Binding Issues

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to call a web api method and return this data to a kendo grid and display this data in my grid. The model that is returned from my web api method has navigation properties that have other objects, and I am just trying to display these navigation elements in my grid using a kendo template. However, I am having problems with it not being able to detect that the navigation property exists, even though I can see it when I debug.

```
 //schema for my kendo data source
 schema: {
              data: function (data) { //specify the array that contains the data
                    console.log("This object has a FREQ_POOL object, and it contains data");
                    console.log(data);

                    var tmp = [{ FREQ_POOL: { IsAM: 'Jane', last: 'Doe' } }, { FREQ_POOL: { IsAM: "John", last: 'Doe' } }];
                    console.log("This object has the same structure and is manually created, and it works if I return it from her in my grid);
                    console.log(tmp);
                  //return tmp; THIS WORKS
                  return  data;  This throws the error FREQ_POOL is undefined
                },                
        }
......................................................
 $("#FAAFreqGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: FAADS,

        columns: [

                { field: "FREQ_POOL", template: "<strong>#: FREQ_POOL.IsAM# </strong>", title: "FAATEST", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }
        ],
        toolbar: ["create"],
        editable: "inline",
        pageable: true

    });
```

When I look at the objects both console.logs return, they look identical in structure. Both have a FREQ_POOL with an IsAM set. But if I return "data" instead of "tmp", I get the error

```
`"Uncaught ReferenceError: FREQ_POOL is not defined"`.
```

So for some reason even though both objects look identical, FREQ_POOL is not being detected in "data", but is in "tmp"

Comment: As far as I remember, complex data isn't supported out-of-the-box in the datasource, however, you could either parse the data which is returning, via: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.parse or to use the data function to update your data before filling the grid. Keep in mind, if you would have to edit these values, you will need some extra work (we used it for sharepoint caml queries, now works perfectly, but was quite some work)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The updating part feels like it would be difficult:( Thanks for the guidance. I guess it was weird because the web api method is returning JSON, so I don't know why it can;t just display the JSON and throws an error when the json looks the exact same as manually creating it.